# Executing the RDS backup/restore stored procedures inside a transaction is not supported. End the transaction before executing the stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services

I am trying to restore a .BAK file from my S3 bucket into my RDS SQL SERVER db. I am using the following command.

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database @restore_db_name='my_db', @s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::backup.bak', @with_norecovery=0
```

The command returns a success message, but after querying it throw `exec msdb.dbo.rds_task_status` it appears as 'CREATED' but '% complete' remains at 0.

After looking at `ERROR.LOG` in the AWS Console I found this message:

> 2022-06-23 15:30:35.80 spid68 Executing the RDS backup/restore stored procedures inside a transaction is not supported. Please end the transaction before executing the stored procedure.

I am running this command exactly as listed above, using SQL Workbench Build 128 Java 11.0.15 and driver `mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre11`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a workaround using `sqlcmd`.

`sqlcmd -S database-1.mydb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -U admin -q "exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database @restore_db_name='my_db', @s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::backup.bak', @with_norecovery=0"`